# how to make if else return in 1 line in function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code below

Is there a way to return the bigger list (1 / 2) in 1 line instead of the last 4 line of if and else in the function?

```py
#Write your function here
def larger_sum(lst1, lst2):
  sum1 = 0
  sum2 = 0
  for num in lst1:
    sum1+=num
  for num in lst2:
    sum2+=num
  if sum1 > sum2:
    return lst1
  else:
    return lst2

#Uncomment the line below when your function is done
print(larger_sum([1, 9, 5], [2, 3, 7]))
```

Comment: I'm sorry it is my first time asking here and it did not include enters

Comment: Is there a specific *problem* with what you've written? If it's working but just longer than you'd like, break it down into smaller problems (e.g. how to calculate the sum of a list) and research those individually to find alternative implementations.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done in one line:

```
def larger_sum(lst1, lst2):
    return max([lst1, lst2], key=sum)
```

The `max` function returns the largest item from its input. When given a key function rather than comparing the items, the results of applying the key function to the items are compared and the item with the largest result from the application of the key function to it is returned.

Comment: Woah thats nice! can you explain the whole max option?

Answer (score 2):

```
if sum1 > sum2:
    return lst1
else:
    return lst2
```

is equivalent to

```
return ls1 if sum1 > sum2 else lst2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
return lst1 if sum1 > sum2 else lst2
```

Answer (score 0):

For me your code looks ok, however if you need 1 line instead of 4 AT ANY PRICE then you might do:

```
def larger_sum(lst1, lst2):
  sum1 = 0
  sum2 = 0
  for num in lst1:
    sum1+=num
  for num in lst2:
    sum2+=num
  return [lst2,lst1][sum1>sum2]
```

Explanation: In Python `True` and `False` are converted to `1` and `0` if need arise, thus if condition is not meet it returns 0-th element (`lst2`) and 1-st element (`lst1`) otherwise (indices starts from 0)

Comment: I just wanted my code to look more clean and with less lines.
It is better to write with least code lines as I heard, right ?

Comment: @Aviran No, it's better to write code so it's readable and understandable

Answer (score 0):

I would write it like this:

```py
def larger_sum(lst1, lst2):
    return lst1 if sum(lst1) > sum(lst2) else lst2
```

Explanation:

In python you can use conditional expressions to return values based on condition or assign them to variables (it's similar to the ternary operator in other languages like java or c++):

`x = val_1 if condition else val_2`

which is equivalent to:

```py
if condition:
    x = val_1
else:
    x = val_2
```

It's a nice syntactic sugar.

In addition, the built in `sum` function takes any iterable (anything that can be used in a `for` loop) and sums its values. This code:

```py
sum_ = 0
for x in lst:
    sum_ += x
```

is equivalent to:

`sum_ = sum(lst)`

The reason I called this variable `sum_` (with a trailing underscore) is to prevent shadowing the built in function `sum` (If I do `sum = ...` and then `s = sum(...)  # trying to sum a list or something` this would cause an error because I've overridden the `sum` function).